hola, tengo un problema con el trigger en sql server
Ejecuto en SQL Server express edition:
CREATE TRIGGER TransAutClientes
ON EXAMENN.CLIENTES
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        -- Insertar los datos desde Oracle en la tabla de SQL Server
        INSERT INTO DBPRUEBAS.dbo.Clientes_ORACLE(Cliente_ID, Nombre, Direccion, Telefono)
        SELECT CLIENTE_ID, NOMBRE, DIRECCION, TELEFONO
        FROM OPENQUERY(A, 'SELECT CLIENTE_ID, NOMBRE, DIRECCION, TELEFONO FROM EXAMENN.CLIENTES');
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Manejar la excepción aquí
        PRINT 'Error durante la transferencia de datos desde Oracle';
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END;

el cual me da el siguiente error:
Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure TransAutClientes, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 23]
The object 'EXAMENN.CLIENTES' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

resalto:
La conexión entre base de datos oracle-sql server está bien porque si me ejecuta otros queries, excepto los triggers.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y existe? la base se llama asi?

¿EXAMENN.CLIENTES es una tabla que está en Oracle?

¿Por qué estás usando OPENQUERY? ¿Lo que buscas es que al insertar en esa tabla también se inserten en la otra?

LO QUE QUIERO ES QUE EL TRIGGER SE ACTUALICE Y TRANSFIERA LOS DATOS DESDE ORACLE A LA TABLA DE SQL SERVER

No puedes crear un trigger en SQL Server para una tabla que está en Oracle. Los triggers son objetos del motor mismo y solamente pueden existir en el contexto del motor y esquema original.
